# Can you print single view fields in a block template file?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I am new to drupal and I am wondering how to gain more control over a view block. Currently I am embedding my view block in my page by doing :

```
<?php print views_embed_view('news_overview', $display_id = 'block'); ?>
```

This works but if I want to style this further I have to go into my view and format it as content and add the html templating there which leaves me with a bit less control than I want.

I made a views-view--block.tpl.php file to try and style my view block a bit more but I am left wondering how to render single view fields here.

I tried doing this to for example render a body field:

```
<?php foreach($view->result as $object): ?>
    <?php print render($object->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['und'][0]['value']); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ofcourse doing this for each field is a hassle and I was wondering if there is an easier way to output view fields inside my **views-view--block.tpl.php** template.

Cheers.

Comment: Why not just remove the fields you don't want to show and only leave the Body field? Or if you want different variations, just make a new block display on the same view and adjust accordingly. Also you can do "Field Templates" if you want to style a particular field in a certain way. Click on "Theme: Information" link on "Advanced" dropdown of your views display when editing.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing do not use that tpl file(**views-view--block.tpl.php**), this will alter all views of your current system. you can use **views-view--news-overview.tpl.php** this will alter your current views view only, there is many suggestions in **views->advanced->theme:information**. you can use appropriate tpl file.